# Make element inside of columns stay at the bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, multiple-columns

I have the following 2 bootstrap columns (each of them has a product description and a price information):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
            </p>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    text
                </li>
                <li>
                    text
                </li>
            </ul>
            <table class="table table-sm table-bordered price-table">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>info</td>
                        <td>info</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>info</td>
                        <td>info</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="table-success">
                        <td>info</td>
                        <td>info</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div>
                <p>
                    Lorem.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
            </p>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    text
                </li>
                <li>
                    text
                </li>
                <li>
                    text
                </li>
                <li>
                    text
                </li>
            </ul>
            <table class="table table-sm table-bordered price-table">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>info</td>
                        <td>info</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>info</td>
                        <td>info</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="table-success">
                        <td>info</td>
                        <td>info</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div>
                <p>
                    Lorem.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As we can see the `ul` elements have a different elements count and hence have a different height, which is very annoying. What I want to achieve is:

- I want the columns to have the same height.
- I want the `table` element to stay always at the bottom of the column, or the `ul` should fill up all 100% of the free area.

How can I do this? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the mb-auto class to the ul. This will push all content below it to the bottom. For this to work you do need the parent container to be a flex container. You have an extra div inside the columns. add d-flex flex-column classes to this div. Alternatively, you can remove the redundant div and add the classes to the column div.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
           ...
        <ul class="mb-auto">
```

I made a codepen with the [demo](https://codepen.io/stevenkuipers/full/RdbEKQ)

edit: When styling the inner div, it needs h-100 to get full height so all columns stay the same height.

Comment: in what way does this not work? You want the columns to have the same height right? This way they will always be as tall as the tallest column in a row.

Comment: It's not working for me because you missed out one `div` after `col-md-4`, which I have in my example.

Comment: If you read my response I tell you that you can style that one or alternatively remove it and style it's parent.

Comment: I need it, I can't remove it.

Comment: then style that one instead of the column  <div class="d-flex flex-column">

Comment: I'm really getting mad :) When I style the inner `div` it won't work, if I do it your way (styling the outer `div` only and commenting out the inner one), it works.

Comment: <div class="d-flex flex-column h-100"> If you add h-100 to inner div it should work

Comment: Thank you very much for you help.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.row .col-md-4 {
  display: flex;
}
.row .col-md-4 > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.row .col-md-4 > div > table {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
      </p>
      <ul>
        <li>
          text
        </li>
        <li>
          text
        </li>
      </ul>
      <table class="table table-sm table-bordered price-table">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="table-success">
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div>
        <p>
          Lorem.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
      </p>
      <ul>
        <li>
          text
        </li>
        <li>
          text
        </li>
        <li>
          text
        </li>
        <li>
          text
        </li>
      </ul>
      <table class="table table-sm table-bordered price-table">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="table-success">
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div>
        <p>
          Lorem.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your new CSS change nothing for me.

Comment: It only shows, when they are next to each other. For that you need to click the `Full page` link on the right in the same line as the `Run code snippet` button

Answer (score -2):

easy solution is adding a height to your ul.

```
ul {
height: 100vh;
}
```

But you should also add rows into your both col-4s.

Comment: Does take up much more space than needed and looks very ugly.

Comment: You can change the value.